# Exception AttributeError from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc' when RUSCORE start!

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, python2.7, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friends!

**i don't know anything about PYYYTHo0o0o0oN** :-s

what am i should to0 do0 whit these exceptionS?

(i have ROS FUERTE)

tnQ

```
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/mohsen/.ros/log/6d9214a4-a0f9-11e2-bd04-00216b5b4a7c/roslaunch-mohsen-ThinkPad-R500-4942.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:57850/
ros_comm version 1.8.10

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [4958]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:11311/

setting /run_id to 6d9214a4-a0f9-11e2-bd04-00216b5b4a7c
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4971]
started core service [/rosout]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60276/exception-attributeerror-from-%27/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc%27-when-ruscore-start!/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, you can safely ignore this error. There are some patches that I know but they only suppress the message.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0